# Age input, making small system with age, and age groups

Tags: python

I'm setting up a small python age system which would ask user to enter his age, and the system should pick a group for user age. For exmpl. If user writes 19 He would be in "Started Niqa" group. I would like to ask what should i use? Float, int, input, number for age and numbers? What does float, int, input used for? I'm new to python, and i would like to learn something new.
P.S You could add some basic sites for me to read. :) I'm using ATOM Editor, Python 3.
Photo of the script. (CODE).
https://gyazo.com/205f880de49947051a346ab555986a31

## Age types

```
age = input("Please enter your age.")

if age <= 18:

    age_group = 'Young Niqa'

elif (age >= 18) and (age <= 21):

    age_group = 'Starter Niqa'

elif (age >= 21) and (age <= 40):

    age_group = 'Experienced Niqa'

elif (age >= 40) and (age <= 100)

age_group = 'Professionall Niqa'

elif(age <= 100) and (age <= 9999)

age_group = 'Dead Niqa'

print(str(name) + "Your age group is -" + age_group)
```

Invalid Syntax error.

Comment: Last two `elif` statements are missing `:` and *indentation*

Comment: What is identation? i put : and i still have error - expected an indented block

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/  start here for resarch ... you can also read this page - there are plenty of ressources in it:  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info

Comment: your conditions can be streamlined: `elif (age >= 18) and (age <= 21):`  can be written as `elif 18 <= age <= 21` ... and you can even omit the lower border. If the person would have been 18 or lower the _first_ if already had taken action and this one would not be checked at all ... so `ìf age <19: ...elif age < 22: ...elif age < 41: .... ` would be shorter and smarter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to read up on the basics of different data types in Python and programming languages in general, particularly the difference between `float` and `int`.  In short though, `int` means an integer, whereas floats are non-integer numbers.  Unless you're dealing with a kid who says stuff like "I'm seven and a half!", then people typically give their ages as integers.

Note however that `input` returns a string typed by the user.  So even if the user typed `7`, that comes back as the string `7`, not the integer.  You need to convert the string to an integer.

```
age = input("Please enter your age: ")

age = int(age)

if age <= 18:
    age_group = 'Young Niqa'
elif (age > 18) and (age <= 21):
    age_group = 'Starter Niqa'
elif (age > 21) and (age < 40):
    age_group = 'Experienced Niqa'
elif (age >= 40) and (age < 100):
    age_group = 'Professional Niqa'
elif(age >= 100) and (age <= 9999):
    age_group = 'Dead Niqa'

print("Your age group is: " + age_group)
```

Some other problems I fixed in your code:

- Two of your `elif`s were missing colons
- They also had bad indentation
- ...and one spelling error
- `<= 100` should be `>= 100`
- And although this isn't a bug, you have some ages belonging to more than one group.  In these cases, the first match is the one taken, with the rest ignored.  Still, I changed some "<=" and ">=" to "<" and ">".

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: But after writing the age, it shows some error: https://gyazo.com/f07e532a69b071152f61e610bdc7caca

Comment: Oh thanks, it was my code.

Comment: Yep, that error you got is due to "age" still being a string in your code.  Adding the `age = int(age)` line, like the one I have here,should fix it.

Comment: Bill M. Also as I'm learning this, maybe you can tell me more about like using these groups to do something? I would like to do lets say a "table" which would pick the group after year (We did that). After the group got picked, let's say it would run another script which would make a list of "printed" stuff to make. I mean, if the user is from group Started, there would be command like Starter_Group = true or something, i don't know how to use this stuff.

Comment: But i would create table like, if the user is from starter_group then: print("Here's stuff for - " + age_group + "You can buy shotgun...."), and for another group other stuff. But as I'm writing this i maybe understood the all thing that I'm trying to explain.

Comment: But i still do not know how to use this if function with this string (starter_group)

Comment: print("Your age group is: " + age_group + "\nAnd you're able to buy" + starter_groupstuff )

Comment: How could i add many strings to starter_groupstuff? I mean like List of items (Text) .

Comment: You could add "starter_groupstuff = ..." commands after each of your "age_group" commands. Though another alternative is to make a Python dictionary where the keys are the age_group strings and the values are a corresponding list of items.  Note though that if starter_groupstuff is an actual Python `list` and not `str`(ing) type, then the `+` won't work.  You'll need to use the Python `join` command to turn your list into a string.  Or use ',' instead of '+'.

Comment: That should look something like this? I just tried to make something like 10 mins ago, and i did this
    if age_group = 'Starter Niqa':
    print("You can buy - shotgun")
    elif age_group = 'Dead Niqa'
    print("you can buy Grenade")

Comment: I would like to make something like this print("~What would you like to buy?\n Here is stuff for Your group -" + starter_groupstuff). After doing this the system automaticly should pick items, and show them in the print dialog, so i wouldn't need to write group_starterstuff = print("......"). I wan't to learn much on this thing ,and I'm trying the best i can to become even better.

Comment: I missed about starter_groupstuff, i mean this print("~What would you like to buy?\n Here is stuff for Your group -" + age_group_stuff) and the age_group_stuff gets the group, that user is in. And show the text dialog

Comment: #-----------Starter Niqa Stuff--------------#
Starter_Items = [Shotgun, rifle, grenade]
print(Starter_Items)
I made a list, but don't know how to make it to string. It should work somehow like this.

Comment: Instead of asking more questions like this in the comments, you should try to word things as a new question and post it as a new question.  Otherwise, it's difficult for people to type the answers you need back to you.  Also, people looking for answers to similar problems in the future will be able to find them better.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the programming languages like C, C++, Java use braces { } to define a block of code. Python uses indentation.

A code block (body of a function, loop etc.) starts with indentation and ends with the first unindented line. The amount of indentation is up to you, but it must be consistent throughout that block.

As @koralp mentioned, your last 2 elif statements are not properly indented. They should look like this:

```
age = input("Please enter your age.")

if age <= 18:

    age_group = 'Young Niqa'

elif (age >= 18) and (age <= 21):

    age_group = 'Starter Niqa'

elif (age >= 21) and (age <= 40):

    age_group = 'Experienced Niqa'

elif (age >= 40) and (age <= 100):

    age_group = 'Professionall Niqa'

elif(age <= 100) and (age <= 9999):

    age_group = 'Dead Niqa'

print(str(name) + "Your age group is -" + age_group)
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d393fb63d6f71b97f4c431acd814166a
Something is still wrong.:(

Comment: @user9745220 on line 35 and 37 of your code. Can you give spaces in the beginning of the line to match with line 33.

Comment: I found out that problem was the lines, i need to put a space between the start of "Proffessionall niqa" and "Dead Niqa" elif.

Comment: @user9745220 if it worked can you select my answer :)